# How to get list of dependency jars from an sbt 0.10.0 project

Tags: scala, sbt, friend

I have a sbt 0.10.0 project that declares a few dependencies somewhat like:

```
object MyBuild extends Build {
    val commonDeps = Seq("commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1",
                         "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6")

    val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq ( organization := "org" )

    lazy val proj = Project("proj", file("src"),
        settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
            name                    := "projname",
            libraryDependencies     := commonDeps, ...)

    ...
}
```

I wish to creat a build rule to gather all the jar dependencies of "proj", so that I can symlink them to a single directory.

Thanks.

Comment: The 'libraryDependencies' value? Think you can start sbt on command line and write lib+<tab> and get suggestions..

Comment: I know the OP asked about sbt 10.0, but for others, I just noted that in 11.3 you can get the class path with "sbt classpath".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Example SBT task to print full runtime classpath**

Below is roughly what I'm using. The "get-jars" task is executable from the SBT prompt.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
object MyBuild extends Build {
  // ...
  val getJars = TaskKey[Unit]("get-jars")
  val getJarsTask = getJars <<= (target, fullClasspath in Runtime) map { (target, cp) =>
    println("Target path is: "+target)
    println("Full classpath is: "+cp.map(_.data).mkString(":"))
  }
  lazy val project = Project (
    "project",
    file ("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(getJarsTask)
  )
}
```

**Other resources**

- [Unofficial guide](http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide) to sbt 0.10.
- [Keys.scala](http://harrah.github.com/xsbt/latest/sxr/Keys.scala.html) defines predefined keys. For example, you might want to replace `fullClasspath` with `managedClasspath`.
- [This plugin](https://github.com/fhars/sbt-ensime-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/EnsimePlugin.scala) defines a simple command to generate an .ensime file, and may be a useful reference.

Comment: Thank you! That unofficial guide link is great wish I'd found it before. BTW you have an awesome name.